# How to redirect to parent virtual directory for Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a web application which consists from two parts the first is in an IIS virtual directory `MainFolder` the second is in a virtual directory `MainFolder/RazorFolder`. The second application is .Net Core Web Application with Razor Pages. I have a page `MainFolder/Default.aspx` and a page `MainFolder/RazorFolder/MyRazorPage`.

When I go to from `default.aspx` to `MyRazorPage` I use

```
Response.Redirect("RazorFolder/MyRazorPage")
```

However I do not know **how to get back**. The only working way is (in an action method)

```
return Redirect("http://localhost/MainFolder/Default.aspx");
```

which is valid in my testing environment only.

Other attempts:

```
return Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

redirects to `http://localhost/MainFolder/RazorFolder/Default.aspx`

```
Url.Content("~/Default.aspx")
```

returns `"/MainFolder/RazorFolder/Default.aspx"`

Hopefull (see [ResolveUrl/ResolveClientUrl equivalents for Asp.Net Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020240/669527)
)

```
@Href("../default.aspx")
```

returns `"../default.aspx"`

So I either need to be able to redirect to parent virtual directory or get full page URL to parse it. Or should I smuggle (with a shame) the return address from the webforms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no method which allows to use double dot (/..) syntax. So it is necessary to get absolute URL, parse it, remove unwanted part and build it again.

Methods allowing to complete the task are in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/) nuget.

1. Full URL: `Request..GetDisplayUrl()`
2. Parse it: `UriHelper.FromAbsolute`
3. Build again processed URL `UriHelper.BuildAbsolute`

So the complete extension method (be aware that the parameter parentRelativeUri has to start with '/'):

```
public static string GetParentUri(this HttpRequest request, string parentRelativeUri)
{
    string scheme;
    HostString host;
    PathString path;
    QueryString query;
    FragmentString fragment;

    UriHelper.FromAbsolute(request.GetDisplayUrl(), out scheme, out host, out path, out query, out fragment);             

    var pathBase = request.PathBase.ToString();

    return UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(scheme, host, 
        pathBase.Substring(0, pathBase.LastIndexOf("/")),
        parentRelativeUri);
}
```

And finally the redirection to parent is:

```
return Redirect(Request.GetParentUri("/Default.aspx"));
```